# Discriminant function for general polynomials

Tags: polynomials

According to Wikipedia... (terrible intro)
The discriminant of a 6-degree polynomial has 246 terms.
The article claims that the relationship between the terms in the discriminant has an exponential relationship to the degree of the equation. On the contrary, I put in the available data into Wolfram Alpha (2,2),(3,5),(4,16),(5,59),(6,246), used interpolate polynomial, and it gave me the equation (11 x^4)/3-(142 x^3)/3+(685 x^2)/3-(1433 x)/3+364.
Plugging 7 into this equation yields 777. Is the number of terms in a general septic discriminant 777, or is it something else? Or is there no discriminant for a general septic equation?

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). You can [edit] your question to improve its readability.

Answer (score 1):

The septic discriminant has 1103 terms.  See [OEIS sequence A007878](http://oeis.org/A007878) for more.